# For what value of $k$, $k\dot{x}=kx-x-x(t-1)$; $x$ will converge to zero?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

what will be the range of k so that x in above mentioned equation converge to zero? How to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

It is a separable ODE, so we can explicitly find the solution $x(t)=c\,e^{t-\frac{t^2}{2k}}$. Consider the limits in cases $k>0$ and $k<0$.